# sed edited files not compatible with windows

Tags: windows, sed, mingw

I used sed -i to edit some files on Windows. After that the files were not recognized by windows. It seems that sed used line feeds other than CR-LF. How can I tell sed to use CR-LF as line feeds? Thanks.

Comment: What sed did you run on MSWin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the `-b` option to retain CR-LF line endings.

`sed --help` would tell you:

```
  -b, --binary
                 open files in binary mode (CR+LFs are not processed specially)
```